# Unable to run spark-shell from terminal on MacOS

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, macos-mojave

I was trying to run spark-shell from terminal on MacOS using `./Documents/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell` and it started running but I wanted to run it using just `spark-shell`.

I saw a [4-minute-video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jFj30A3L3k) that shows how it's done but it isn't working for me.

I don't fully understand how `~/.bash_profile` work but below is how it looks like:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/ajay/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/ajay/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/ajay/Documents/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Users/ajay/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

The **$PATH** gives `/usr/local/bin:/Users/ajay/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

How do I need to change the `~/.bash_profile` for `spark-shell` to work?

**EDIT**

Here is the message that I get with on running `./Documents/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell`

```
20/08/27 16:51:16 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.2:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1598527288778).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
```

On running `spark-shell` it shows : `-bash: spark-shell: command not found`

Comment: Have you tried running `spark-shell` in the console? Did it work? What was the error message?

Comment: @thsutton In the edits

Comment: ~/.bash_profile is read only on login...

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Users/ajay/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

These two lines are in the wrong order, in that you "add" the spark installation to the `$PATH` and then immediately overwrite `$PATH`.

You might prefer to have something like:

```
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:/Users/ajay/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Don't forget that any changes to `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc` will only take effect in a new shell (unless you manually load them).

Comment: So the 2 export lines should be after the `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Users/ajay/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` line?

Comment: There's no need to have multiple lines; you can just have a single line that does `export PATH="new:things:followed:by:$PATH